# Auto_now_add Django Weird Bug

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using Postgresql 9.3.4, Windows 7 64 Bit, Django 1.6.5.

I had one model (A MODEL) with one field (B FIELD) using auto_now_add. When my application add record to A MODEL, I didn't have problem in the past. Until today (16 June 2014), I got Django integrity error because when my application add record to A MODEL, null value will be added to B FIELD.

I thought it was bug on my application / code. However, when I change the date on my Windows OS e.g. 15 June 2014/17 June 2014, I can add record on B FIELD to A MODEL without any integrity error. It works properly, as expected from my code.

Here's the snapshot from A MODEL

```
class Reservation (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'ghb_manager'

    RESERVATION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('RSV', 'Reservation'),
        ('WI', 'Walk In'),
    )

    reservation_id = models.CharField(max_length=14, primary_key=True)
    identity_number = models.ForeignKey(Guest, db_column='identity_number')
    total = models.IntegerField()
    ammount_due = models.IntegerField()
    departure = models.DateField()
    arrival = models.DateField()
    reservation_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=RESERVATION_TYPE_CHOICES)
    reservation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.reservation_id
```

Here's the snapshot of my code, adding a record causing the integrity error:

```
rs = Reservation(reservation_id = reservation_code, identity_number = guest, departure = departureRaw, arrival = arrival, total = total, ammount_due = total, reservation_type = "Walk In")
rs.save()
```

Have anyone experienced this problem? If so, please give me some guidance about this bug. Until now, I'm dazzled with this bug.

Here's my traceback error log

```
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792] Internal Server Error: /ghb_manager/add_walkin
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 112, in get_response
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\transaction.py", line 431, in inner
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "c:/xampp/htdocs/ghb22\\ghb_manager\\views\\add.py", line 325, in walkin_add
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     rs.save()
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\base.py", line 545, in save
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\base.py", line 573, in save_base
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\base.py", line 635, in _save_table
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     forced_update)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\base.py", line 679, in _do_update
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     return filtered._update(values) > 0
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\query.py", line 510, in _update
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\sql\\compiler.py", line 980, in execute_sql
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\sql\\compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     cursor.execute(sql, params)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\util.py", line 69, in execute
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\util.py", line 53, in execute
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\util.py", line 53, in execute
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792] IntegrityError: null value in column "reservation_date" violates not-null constraint
[Mon Jun 16 22:49:19.625868 2014] [:error] [pid 2440:tid 1792] DETAIL:  Failing row contains (WI20140616008, 6472052107880006, 270000, 270000, 2014-06-17, 2014-06-16, Walk In, null).
```

I also tested the system again today (17 June 2014), and I can add record properly now without any integrity errors.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the _entire_ traceback of the error you receive.

Comment: Hi Burhan, I've added my error traceback on the question

Comment: What is your date locale?

Comment: What is the result of `datetime.date.today()` if you set your date to 16th?

Comment: And, have you had any daylight savings changes around this date?

Comment: I don't have daylight savings on my country, even the Windows OS also disable the daylight savings.

Comment: datetime.date.today will print 16-06-2014

Comment: Can you reproduce this error from `manage.py shell`?